# parse.com difference between request.object and request.params

Tags: parse-platform

I'm running through the parse.com tutorial,

https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

and it mentions that when i'm doing some cloud code, I should get the json values using `request.params.someParam`

All well and good, except the tutorial then *immediately* starts making calls to `request.object.get("someParam")`

What is the difference between request.object.get() and request.params.theParam? Is one better than the other? Is this a standard javascript thing that i should know (i don't know js a whole bunch)

Comment: Is it just me or is the `request` object not being passed into the function properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are two different concepts. One is used in Cloud Functions, the other in object saving triggers.

- `request.params` is used in Cloud Functions to access GET/POST parameters.
- `request.object` is used in beforeSave/afterSave triggers to access the object being saved.

Comment: inside a beforeSave trigger, if I make an operation on a request.object .. do I need to call request.object.save(null, successHandlerObj); ?  Or is save automatic.

Comment: Can we send object as parameters {emp:employee} on cloud function and receive it in request.params.emp ?. When i tried, i got following error message "Uncaught Parse.Objects not allowed here "

Comment: Yes you can. Add a new question with more details if you still run into issues.

Comment: @Ramesh_D, did you ever find a solution to "Uncaught Parse.Objects not allowed here " ? I have the exact same use case and the exact same problem.